# Implementing Form that Might Result in Different Queries

Tags: php, forms, user-experience

I have a form that needs to allow people to search for hikes, hiking groups, or hikers, depending on what radio button they choose within the form.

Obviously, in either of these 3 cases, the query will be of different tables in the database, and have different usability down the road.  So I probably shouldn't process all of these in one place I am assuming.  Would you guys agree?

What might be a good practice way to handle such a case?  I tried redirecting the request to single form processing modules, but I had trouble making a POST request in the URL that I was trying to redirect.

Ideas/suggestions appreciated,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem handling this from 1 form. pass on the search type and build an appropriate query based on the type, search terms, etc.  Even if the queries are totally different, it sounds like the input your gathering is pretty simple.  You may want to display the results with different pages, but processing can easily be handled with one form and one script.

Quick example:

```
//get variables out of POST

if ($search_type == "hike")
{
    //put together a hike query, get results
    //call script to display hikes
}
elseif ($search_type == "group")
{
    //put together a group query, get results
    //call script to display hikes
}
elseif(...) //etc, etc
```

Comment: I get that, but this doesn't seem like a good solution because of further UX.  Problem #1 is that this will cause lots of clutter in further if/elses which will depend on the outcome of this if/else.  Problem #2 is that since I have a script and not a full controller, I am not sure how to redirect to the pages that would display the different data: hikes/groups/hikers

Comment: If you're that worried about a complex script to handle the various searches, you may want to consider separate forms.  You could even use JavaScript to change the action of the script based on the selected search type.  Alternately, you could build an object to handle the searches and results, which would be defined in a separate file. Also, you don't have to redirect to display the results, just include a script that's prepared to display the results.  Finally, if "clutter" is a serious problem, consider creating multiple scripts and include them as needed for various behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the value for the radio button and call different methods for further handling the form. That way you can put the queries and any related code in totally different files. 
Where exactly do you see a problem in that? In how is the handling behind the screens related to user-experience?

Comment: I think although I can call different queries without a problem, the problem is that I will need to display the things in 3 different ways depending on the nature of the data. I think its more of an eventual redirect and usability issue that I trying to figure out.

Comment: Well, I can't look in your code and I don't know if you're using any frameworks that force you into a rigid structure, but I would say you could just generate any of 3 structures of data with your queries and include the right template to display each chunk. If you use an `if` or `switch` you can write code there, but you can also call other functions or include an entire file within that if. It should be very doable without cluttering your code.